# GraphPropertyDistribution and VertexDegree

Tags: graphs-and-networks

`GraphPropertyDistribution` (in v. 11.0) works in some simple cases:

```
d[n_Integer,p_] = GraphPropertyDistribution[
  VertexDegree[g],
  g \[Distributed] BernoulliGraphDistribution[n, p]]
```

(* BinomialDistribution[1/2 (-1 + n) n, p] *)

Is the reason the following example does not resolve to a symbolic solution due to the fact that there *is* no analytic solution (I doubt this) or instead that *Mathematica* simply cannot compute it (yet)?

```
ee[n_Integer, p_] = Assuming[n \[Element] Integers,
 GraphPropertyDistribution[
  VertexDegree[g],
  g \[Distributed] BernoulliGraphDistribution[n, p]]]
```

Comment: Is your first example correct? It doesn't evaluate for me, even after removing the extra bracket at the end. Also, it seems to be exactly the same expression as in the second case, minus the `Assuming`?

Comment: @LukasLang:  Thanks... I forgot a definition (now fixed).  But the problem remains.  I don't need the Assuming, but I thought it might be needed for the second snippet of code.  Maybe not.

Comment: (1) In the first code block `VertexDegree[g]` should be `EdgeCount[g]` ? (2) All the examples in the docs are for scalar properties _such as edge count, vertex count, length of shortest path, number of connected components_.  So using a scalar property `GraphPropertyDistribution[VertexDegree[g, 1], 
 g \[Distributed] BernoulliGraphDistribution[n, p]]` and `GraphPropertyDistribution[VertexDegree[g, _],  g \[Distributed] BernoulliGraphDistribution[n, p]]` both give  `BinomialDistribution[-1 + n, p]`

Comment: .. and, as expected, `GraphPropertyDistribution[VertexCount[g], 
 g \[Distributed] BernoulliGraphDistribution[n, p]]` gives `DiscreteUniformDistribution[{n, n}]`